# evenly space varying number of elements in a div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of words that I want to put in styled divs which should together span accross the entire screen width.

It is easy when I know that there are e.g. 3 items:

```
 <div class="col-xs-4">
    pending
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-4">
    accepted
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-4">
    completed
 </div>
```

This fills the entire width with evenly spaced containers (with some added css):

[image]

I would like to have this done dynamically since I load those contents (pending,accepted,...) from a DB and there may be any number of such items, rather than exactly three. Any idea of how to do that?

Comment: I happen to disagree with the accepted answer on the linked duplicate question. Here's [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/1thjm35f/) to demonstrate my point.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I just had a look at your solution and it is very good. I did not realize that the containers adapt to the content since all my content (words) were of very similar length. I changed my code now and all boxes are of exactly equal size. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. I apologise for misunderstanding your question earlier.